# Edit java class file of AWS-SNS SDK for Unity

Tags: java, unity-game-engine, amazon-sns

I am using AWS-SNS SDK for Unity to receive notification in Android Device.
After I import asset package to Unity Editor, I can setup everything and receive notification. However there is no title of notification. I should change source of sdk. I want to edit 'Utils.java' inside 'aws-unity-sns-gcm-helper.jar' file. But it is very hard to change class file inside jar file. Futhermore, there are java files before jar-generated inside sdk(AWSUnityGCMWrapper.java, GCMBroadcastReceiver.java, GCMIntentService.java, Utils.java). Is there any way to use java files instead of jar file? Where can I set up for that?
Thanks.

Comment: Did you have any luck with this Jade? How do you do it? Nika misunderstands you, I can see you need to recompile the .java files if you wish to to edit the default Android notifications.

Answer (score 1):

Buddy, you are using the deprecated version of AWS SDK. The new SDK is integrated directly in Unity without jars and java files. It's a .NET library. Check it out on github:

https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net

and here you can see how you can build it for Unity:

https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/blob/master/Unity.README.md

Comment: Thanks, but this is for SNS function only. SNS functions are to get regID and create Topic and subscribe in AWS Server. Inside SDK package there is a gcm helper jar file to help android device receive notification with native java mothod. I generated new jar file with Eclipse. But it is still annoying..Thanks...

Comment: mate, the first link on github states - clone repo "then include the assemblies for the services needed as well as the core assembly", then build. You can only include SNS assembly if you desire so.